# Why is this question locked?

Tags: discussion, support, locked-question

[What words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1431/10041)

If it's not a good question for the site, why isn't it closed?  I'd like to vote, at least.

Maybe I don't understand what locking is for, but I had assumed that it was for keeping votes and edits off a closed question.  Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question has 123 answers already. Nobody reads them all, nobody votes on them all. We probably don't *need* them all, let alone more. But it's a soft question, so everybody feels entitled to answer — again, without so much as checking if their answer has already been posted.

The question needs constant babysitting. We get duplicate answers, answers that list several words at once, thinly-veiled peeving, outright rants. And every single one of them bumps the question to the front page *again*.

But even with all the attention they generate for the question  — 6,540 views as of the time of writing  —, the new answers themselves still don't attract votes. The youngest thirty answers have a combined score of fifty. That's less than two upticks on average, after all this time (these answers may be the youngest, but they are still up to ten months old).

When new answers stop attracting votes and start attracting flags, some of them openly asking to lock the question, it's time to do just that.

There were never any close votes on the question itself, though, so I saw no reason to close it unilaterally. (But of course we can talk about closing it and putting up our usual "this question exists for historical reasons" banner. I have no strong feelings one way or the other.)

Comment: I think under the current going rule where "list questions are bad", this may be a prime example for closing but leaving the "historical reasons" banner.

Comment: @Simchona Seconded.  Then I wouldn't be confused anymore! :)

Comment: @simchona: Okay, I'm sold. How do I vote for that?

Comment: @FumbleFingers--Maybe flag the question, and if enough of us flag we can get it closed.