# Historical lock instead of closure for high view questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Today I found [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72713/the-meaning-of-mingle) in my review queue for a close vote. It's mostly my fault because I edited a previously burninated tag out and bumped it to the front page by doing so. Naturally, another user came along and voted to close the question for being primarily opinion based. I explicitly do not want to discuss the merit of that vote or the specific question that brought the topic up. It is just to stand in as an example.

Basically we have questions that don't necessarily meet our ELU standards of today in the treasure trove that is our question archive. Some of those questions have a lot of views. Some of those have a lot of views. We also have the possibility to put a [historic lock on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/338924). We do this for questions [like this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me) by [flagging the post for moderator attention](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/how-can-users-nominate-old-popular-questions-for-exemption-from-closure-as-bein).

It seems to me that the close votes are a bit redundant on the bear question and the question should have been flagged for historical locking in the first place.

What's the general requirement for historical locks?

Is there a rule of thumb where a moderator on ELU will likely approve the lock? 10k views? 50 votes? Something like that besides what's in the meta.se post? Otherwise it would be *safer* to vote for closure and flag in case the moderator declines the flag.

Comment: The article you linked to on historical locks actually has a good list of "when is it appropriate" and "when is it not appropriate". Beyond those, what are you looking for as general requirements for historical locks?

Comment: @MetaEd mainly what's considered *large number of views or votes* on ELU since those numbers are very site specific.